# Microsoft Cognitive Services: Unable to run Video api on Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-cognitive-services

**How I did:**
I have cloned the project and followed the instructions given in [This link](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Video/Windows),

section: build the sample, run the sample

**Error:**
Unable to load Video.sdk

[image: enterdescription here]

[image]

I have installed the visual studio with update 2 already, why does it asks for an update 1 ? the pop up came up when I right clicked on Video.sdk and reload

Comment: Zillani, I am unable to see video api inside cognitive services. I have taken free trial. Could you please tell me how did you get video api unser cognitive services. And generate KEY